# error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "moc'ing qt/gui/QFloatSlider.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I'm building a big C++ project on Visual Studio 2008  I'm getting this error message and I don't understand it. Is it a failure to include the .h file?

Answer (score 5):

I know this thread is dated, but I had the exact same problem with a C++ project on Visual Studio 2008, here was my resolution...

One of the things the VS2008 compile told me was that it generated a log on:
"file://C:\Documents and Settings\adam\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\MyProject\Debug\BuildLog.htm"

This log demystified the problem for me.
In my case, it had the following explicit error message:
c:\Documents and Settings\adam\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\UnitTests.h(36): Error: Meta object features not supported for nested classes

The problem had been that INSIDE the class I defined here, I defined yet another internal (nested) class, that included the QT macro (so I could define signals and slots):
Q_OBJECT

Obviously QT wasn't happy that this class was nested/internal in another class. So I simply moved the class definition outside (IE made it non-internal).

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not.
Did you look up the error code **[error PRJ0019](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzk29wdw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)**.

Comment: "This error can also occur when you are running as a member of the Users group and Administrative access is needed."

Comment: ^ I'm the administrator of this Windows machine, I don't get that.